# The node is down, but there are no exceptions in the logs

Tags: linux, database, time-series, cnosdb

I created a single-node container. After running it for a few days, the node hung up, but no problems were found in the logs and system logs. What was going on?

I checked the cnosdb log and the deadline is 20240120203253, as follows：

`2024-01-20T20:32:53.963266264Z  INFO tskv::compaction::picker: Picker: Calculate level scores: [ { Level-1: 1.6 }, { Level-4: 1.6 }, { Level-3: 0.4 } ]`

`2024-01-20T20:32:53.963393433Z  INFO tskv::compaction::picker: Picker: picked level: 1 to 2`

`2024-01-20T20:32:53.965405243Z  INFO tskv::compaction::picker: Picker: picked L1 files(2) does not reach trigger(4), return None`

`2024-01-20T20:32:53.965539938Z  INFO tskv::compaction::job: Starting compaction on ts_family 3`

`2024-01-20T20:32:53.965603168Z  INFO tskv::compaction::picker: Picker: picked no level`

`2024-01-20T20:32:53.966003610Z  INFO tskv::compaction::job: Compacting on vnode(job start): {12: true, 6: true, 3: true} costs 0 sec`

and I check the sys log with dmesg -T,as follow:

`[六 1月 20 10:05:16 2024] [36395]    89 36395    22974      268      48        0             0 pickup`

`[六 1月 20 10:05:16 2024] Out of memory: Kill process 32449 (tokio-runtime-w) score 671 or sacrifice child`

`[六 1月 20 10:05:16 2024] Killed process 32449 (tokio-runtime-w), UID 0, total-vm:323738056kB, anon-rss:179339976kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB`

`[六 1月 20 10:06:14 2024] docker0: port 1(veth798dd8b) entered disabled state`

`[六 1月 20 10:06:14 2024] docker0: port 1(veth798dd8b) entered disabled state`

The latest OOM log is very different from the cnosdb log. So why is the cnosdb service down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After subsequent trigger OOM testing, it was found that the OOM log time recorded by the system would deviate to a certain extent from the system time. According to the offset time, we locate the system log from the last log printed by cnosdb, and there is a record of Cnosd DB process OOM.
as follow:

1. System log expiration time before triggering OOM

```
dmesg -T
...
[Wed Jan 24 20:53:41 2024] docker0: port 7(xxx) entered forwarding state
```

2. current time

```
[root@xxx ~]# date
Mon Jan 29 10:30:39 CST 2024
```

3. Trigger OOM

```
[root@cicd_ujv23 ~]# stress --vm 10 --vm-bytes 25G --vm-keep
stress: info: [38900] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 10 vm, 0 hdd
stress: FAIL: [38900] (415) <-- worker 38904 got signal 9
stress: WARN: [38900] (417) now reaping child worker processes
stress: FAIL: [38900] (415) <-- worker 38910 got signal 9
stress: WARN: [38900] (417) now reaping child worker processes
stress: FAIL: [38900] (451) failed run completed in 40s
```

4. check the OOM log:

```
dmesg -T
[Sun Jan 28 11:59:09 2024] Out of memory: Kill process 38910 (stress) score 92 or sacrifice child
[Sun Jan 28 11:59:09 2024] Killed process 38910 (stress), UID 0, total-vm:26221716kB, anon-rss:25472716kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```